# Haskell list comprehension with "x is drawn from a function"

Tags: list, function, haskell, types

The code below starting with `digits` returns a List of integers. The code starting with `altSumOfDigits` should return just the same list, but instead Prelude is complaining about a type error, which i don't understand at this point.

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type `Integer'


digits' :: Integer -> [Integer]
digits' 0 = []
digits' x = (x `mod` 10) : digits' (x `div` 10)

digits :: Integer -> [Integer]
digits 0 = [0]
digits x = reverse $ digits' x

altSumOfDigits :: Integer -> [a]
altSumOfDigits num = [ x | x <- (digits num)]
```

(I know that `altSumOfDigits num = [ x | x <- (digits num)]` is rather useless in this form. I'm going to extend its functionality with an if-expression and operations on the single Integers later.)
Any explanations why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change (or remove) the type of `altSumOfDigits` to return a `[Integer]`.

---

Including the error in the question is good form, and here it is:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `Integer'
```

The type of `altSumOfDigits` takes a list of `Integer`, but returns a list of any type `a`, according to the type you have declared. So it is polymorphic in its return type.

However, you call `digits` from within `altSumOfDigits`, which *must* return a list of `Integer` only. There is thus no way your `altSumOfDigits` could return anything other than a list of `[Integer]`.

Comment: So the type [a] isn't just a super-type of [Integer]. I thought that [a] or solo a (or anything with a) could be placeholder for any other type. Thanks for your catch.

Comment: No, not a placeholder. It is a requirement you state to the compiler that it must work for all types.